# Finding range, continuity and derivability of a function defined by cases

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^2\sin\frac{1}{x^2}  & \text{$x\neq 0$} \\[2ex]
0 & \text{$x=0$}
\end{cases}$ and let $g(x)=f'(x)$.

Find its range, continuity and derivability range (the range in which it can be derivated).

I don't know how to do that for $g(x)$. Can you please show me how to find the derivability range of $g(x)$?

Thank you in advance, I don't know what to do. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

For $x\not=0$, 
$$g(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2\sin\frac{1}{x^2} \right)=?$$
For $x=0$, 
$$g(0)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{h\to 0}h\sin\frac{1}{h^2}=?$$
Can you take it from here?